#  matching unicode characters in python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, unicode, non-ascii-characters, character-properties

I have read thru the other questions at Stackoverflow, but still no closer. Sorry, if this is allready answered, but I didn`t get anything proposed there to work.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r'^/by_tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/(?P<filename>(\w|[.,!#%{}()@])+)$', '/by_tag/xmas/xmas1.jpg')
>>> print m.groupdict()
{'tag': 'xmas', 'filename': 'xmas1.jpg'}
```

All is well, then I try something with Norwegian characters in it ( or something more unicode-like ):

```
>>> m = re.match(r'^/by_tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/(?P<filename>(\w|[.,!#%{}()@])+)$', '/by_tag/påske/øyfjell.jpg')
>>> print m.groupdict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

How can I match typical unicode characters, like øæå? I`d like to be able to match those characters as well, in both the tag-group above and the one for filename.

Comment: Make sure you [normalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) your strings because there are diffent codepoint-sequences generating the same visual apperance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to specify the `re.UNICODE` flag, *and* input your string as a Unicode string by using the `u` prefix:

```
>>> re.match(r'^/by_tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/(?P<filename>(\w|[.,!#%{}()@])+)$', u'/by_tag/påske/øyfjell.jpg', re.UNICODE).groupdict()
{'tag': u'p\xe5ske', 'filename': u'\xf8yfjell.jpg'}
```

This is in Python 2; in Python 3 you must leave out the `u` because all strings are Unicode, and you can leave off the `re.UNICODE` flag.

Comment: +1 for: and input your string as a Unicode string by using the u prefix

Comment: I don't understand, why do we need to pass in `re.UNICODE`? (I'm using python 3)

Comment: @CharlieParker Notice the date of this answer :) In Python 3, `re.UNICODE` does nothing.

Answer (score 13):

You need the [UNICODE](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag:

```
m = re.match(r'^/by_tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/(?P<filename>(\w|[.,!#%{}()@])+)$', '/by_tag/påske/øyfjell.jpg', re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Is it required for Python3 too?

Comment: @Kevin  - you don't need the unicode flag with Python 3. "Unicode matching is already enabled by default in Python 3 for Unicode (str) patterns..." - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: I don't understand, why do we need to pass in `re.UNICODE`? (I'm using python 3)

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2, you need the [re.UNICODE](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag and the [unicode](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode) string constructor

```
>>> re.sub(r"[\w]+","___",unicode(",./hello-=+","utf-8"),flags=re.UNICODE)
u',./___-=+'
>>> re.sub(r"[\w]+","___",unicode(",./cześć-=+","utf-8"),flags=re.UNICODE)
u',./___-=+'
>>> re.sub(r"[\w]+","___",unicode(",./привет-=+","utf-8"),flags=re.UNICODE)
u',./___-=+'
>>> re.sub(r"[\w]+","___",unicode(",./你好-=+","utf-8"),flags=re.UNICODE)
u',./___-=+'
>>> re.sub(r"[\w]+","___",unicode(",./你好，世界-=+","utf-8"),flags=re.UNICODE)
u',./___\uff0c___-=+'
>>> print re.sub(r"[\w]+","___",unicode(",./你好，世界-=+","utf-8"),flags=re.UNICODE)
,./___，___-=+
```

(In the latter case, the comma is Chinese comma.)

Comment: I don't understand, why do we need to pass in `re.UNICODE`? (I'm using python 3)