# Regular expressions dont like international characters

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [matching unicode characters in python regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028717/matching-unicode-characters-in-python-regular-expressions)

Using

```
re.findall(r'\w+', ip)
```

on `Fältskog` returns `F` and `ltskog`. I tried with both strings and unicode but the same. result

Comment: You need to specify the re.LOCALE and re.UNICODE flags. (If you want to depend on the current locale, otherwise, re.UNICODE will match all alphanumeric in all languages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the [appropriate](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) [flags](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents) (in this case [`UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) to tell `re` what `\w` means):

```
re.findall(r'\w+', ip, re.UNICODE)

# EDIT

Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"\w+", u"Fältskog", re.UNICODE)
[u'F\xe4ltskog']
>>>
```

Comment: This returned `['F\xc3', 'ltskog']`, not as a single word. Please check it.

Comment: My bad, I gave it a non-unicode string to start with. Accepted this.

Answer (score 0):

re.findall(r'[åäöÅÄÖ\w]+', ip)

You can also do this if you want to be more visual.