# Python regex tokenization of Unicode string not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, unicode, tokenize

I encounter a strange problem with regular expression tokenization and Unicode strings.

```
> mystring = "Unicode rägular expressions"
> tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', mystring, re.UNICODE)
```

This is what I get:

```
> print tokens
['Unicode', 'r\xc3', 'gular', 'expressions']
```

This is what I expected:

```
> print tokens
['Unicode', 'rägular', 'expressions']
```

What do I have to do to get the expected result?

Update: This question is different from mine:  [matching unicode characters in python regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5028717/1251687) But it's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028826/1251687 would have solved my problem, too.

Comment: `\w` does not include Unicode characters like ä.

Comment: what's the way to do it then?

Comment: \w includes unicode if you use re.UNICODE.

Comment: @Xufox: it does when you use the `re.UNICODE` flag.

Comment: At issue here is that you are trying to match *encoded bytes*, not Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Wow, Python RegEx is somewhat different from what I’m used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string must be unicode.

```
mystring = u"Unicode rägular expressions"
tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', mystring, re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: That's it. Python Unicode is a massive headache...

Comment: @boadescriptor: Watch http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html to reduce that headache. Stick to the Unicode sandwich, avoid handling encoded bytes as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

You have Latin-1 or Windows Codepage 1252 bytes, not Unicode text. Decode your input:

```
tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', mystring.decode('cp1252'), re.UNICODE)
```

An encoded byte can mean anything depending on the codec used, it is not a specific Unicode codepoint. For byte strings (type `str`) only ASCII characters can be matched when using `\w`.