# python to select text from mixed codes

Tags: python, regex, text

### updates so far:

beautifulsoup works partly. How to remove whatever text between `<style>` and `<\style>`?

---

I am trying to write a function so that from such a text

```
<style>.card {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}
</style>qüestion

<hr id=answer>

änswer
```

to get only these out

```
word[0] = qüestion
word[1] = änswer
```

the words could contain umlauts.

I thought `re` or `regex`could probably do the job, but I couldn't succeed! Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matching unicode characters in python regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028717/matching-unicode-characters-in-python-regular-expressions)

Comment: regex is generally regarded as not the ways to parse HTML, check beautifulsoup or lxml if you can.

Comment: I have checked the link given as the possible duplicate. It is still unclear nad I would appreciate some hint!

Comment: @JosepValls Thanks, beautifulsoup works parly and removes `<hr id=answer>`, `<style>` and `<\style>`. How would it be possible to delete whatever text between `<style>` and `<\style>` is?

Comment: @Amin: I believe you can do that with `soup.find("style").clear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove whatever text between `<style>` and `</style>`?

You need to [`extract()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) the `style` tags or [`clear()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear) them:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<style>.card {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}
</style>question

<hr id=answer>

answer'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
>>> styles = [style.extract() for style in soup('style')] # Or, you may use...
>>> # soup.find("style").clear()
>>> results = soup.text.strip().split()
>>> print(results)
[u'question', u'answer']
```

With `[style.extract() for style in soup('style')]`, you get all the `style` tags with their inner HTML and remove them from `soup`. Then, its `text` property only contains `question` and `answer` separated with some whitespace, so all you need to do is split the string.